# Create a script that takes a word as an argument from the user

Tags: bash, sh

```
echo "Enter your string"  
read str;
```

How can I put in a check to make sure the user passed in a word, displaying
a usage statement if a word was not passed as an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you'd like to force the user to enter a string, not a numeric value, and keep asking until the input fullfills the requirement, I'd definitely use a test in a while loop, like:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; 
do
  echo "Enter your string"
  read str;
  echo "${str}" | grep -q '[0-9]'
  if [ $? != 0 ] && [ "$str" != "" ] ; then
    break
  else 
    echo 'Invalid input' 
  fi
done
# use the input for further processing
echo $str
```

(using the test from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3285201/1391444))

Answer (score 2):

```
[ "$str" ] || { echo "This is my usage statement"; exit 1; }
```

This uses `test`, denoted by `[...]`. In its simplest form, as used here, it merely tests if the string is non-empty (returning success/true) or empty (returning fail/false).  The control operator, `||`, executes the statement which follows only if the preceding statement returned false.

I assumed that, if the user failed to enter a non-empty `str`, that you would want to exit with a failure code after issuing the usage statement.  If not, remove the `exit 1`.

If you have something more complex to do, then use a more formal `if` statement:

```
if [ "$str" ]
then
    echo "This is my usage statement"
    # do other stuff....
    exit 1
fi
```

The above should work on any POSIX shell including `dash` (`/bin/sh`) and `bash`.

#### Other Tests

Here are two related tests (both require `bash`):

```
[ "${str//[^[:digit:]]/}" ] || { echo "You entered no numbers"; exit 1; }
```

And,

```
[ "${str//[^[:alpha:]]/}" ] || { echo "You entered no letters"; exit 1; }
```

Comment: how i check user passed, maybe user passed number or letter with number?

Comment: @qwerty See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try use string$, and enter in the terminal this:

echo "enter you name" ; string$
   read string$

and it might work fine this way.

Comment: it's a joke? ) do not worked