# Cant read variable from user input in bash

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, sh

I try to run script of my friend and I get this error when try to input some variable:

```
: bad variable nameead: reload
: not foundsh: 10: bin/reload.sh: 
bin/reload.sh: 11: bin/reload.sh: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting "in")
```

Where is the problem? Here is the code of sh script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo ""
echo "Выберите необходимое действие:"
echo "    1 - reload."
echo "    2 - db."
echo "    3 - tests."
echo "    0 - exit."
read reload

case $reload in
1)
echo "reload."
php composer.phar update
php vendor/sensio/distribution-bundle/Sensio/Bundle/DistributionBundle/Resources/bin/build_bootstrap.php

rm -rf app/cache/*
rm -rf app/logs/*
touch app/logs/error.log

APACHEUSER=`ps aux | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1`

mkdir -p web/upload/media
rm -rf web/upload/media/*
rm -rf web/upload/dream/*
rm -rf web/upload/tmp/*

setfacl -R -m u:"$APACHEUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX app/cache app/logs web/upload
setfacl -dR -m u:"$APACHEUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX app/cache app/logs web/upload

php app/console doctrine:database:drop --force
php app/console doctrine:database:create
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
php app/console cache:clear
php app/console doctrine:fixtures:load --no-interaction
php app/console assets:install --symlink
php app/console assetic:dump
php app/console cache:clear
;;
2)
echo "reload db."
php app/console doctrine:database:drop --force
php app/console doctrine:database:create
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
php app/console doctrine:fixtures:load --no-interaction
php app/console assets:install --symlink
php app/console assetic:dump
php app/console cache:clear
;;
3)
echo ""
echo "tests:"
echo "    1 - Запуск всех тестов."
echo "    2 - Запуск юнит тестов."
echo "    0 - Выход."
read testing

case $testing in
1)
    echo "Запуск всех тестов."
    php app/console doctrine:database:drop --force
    php app/console doctrine:database:create
    php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
    php app/console cache:clear
    php app/console doctrine:fixtures:load --no-interaction
    php app/console cache:clear

    sh bin/tests.sh
;;
2)
    echo "Запуск юнит тестов."
    php app/console doctrine:database:drop --force
    php app/console doctrine:database:create
    php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
    php app/console cache:clear
    php app/console doctrine:fixtures:load --no-interaction
    php app/console cache:clear

    bin/phpunit -c app
;;
0)
    exit 0
;;
*)
    echo "Введите правильное действие!"
    sh bin/reload.sh

esac
;;
0)
exit 0
;;
*)
echo "Введите правильное действие!"
sh bin/reload.sh

esac
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a script that takes a word as an argument from the user](http://askubuntu.com/questions/544186/create-a-script-that-takes-a-word-as-an-argument-from-the-user)

Comment: that couldn't be the whole script. It's missing a lot of things (the `esac` to start with).

Comment: @Rmano, its just a part of it, part where i getting error

Comment: You should put a complete snippet that shows the problem. The script (with the correct `esac` and the syntax of case adjusted) runs just fine here, so the error is elsewhere.

Comment: @Rmano, i added entire script)

Comment: Still works here (checked with 0, I have no php installed). You should have some strange configuration. Are you sure you have not aliased "reload" somehow?

Comment: hm..no. Its not my script I download it from github

Comment: The strange run-together lines in your error output (`nameead`, `foundsh`)  may indicate that there are spurious non-printing characters in your script file - most likely Windows line endings (`\r`). Use `cat -A reload.sh` to check for control sequences like `^M`.

Comment: Did you check if bin/reload.sh is a shell script? It could be a bash script.

Comment: I solve this problem.

Comment: If you want you can wirte your own answer, to help people with same problem :)

Comment: @Letizia, sure, maybe it helps someone)

Comment: @Letizia bash scripts _are_ shell scripts. You mean an `sh` script which is simply a different shell.

Comment: yes @terdon, I supposed sh could points to different shell respect script. I'm not sure if it can be happends on Ubuntu :)

Comment: @Letizia yes, the default `sh` on Ubuntu and Debian is `/bin/dash`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve this problem. It was very simple. I need to change ends of strings to Unix/Linux format in my .sh file instead of Windows ends.